# server is being used for ddos attacks, any scripts to search for these?

Tags: ssh, ddos

One of our vps' on rackspace is being used for ddos'ing which means we have a vulnerability somewhere. Is there any ssh scripts or tools that can scan for scripts doing this?

Comment: What platform is this on?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following the advice of one of our Excellent community ads:

[image]